# Using pipenv on base conda

Tags: conda, pipenv

I have conda installed. I want to use pipenv. It is advised that i use pipenv outside of conda environment, since it is also an environment. But what makes me irritated is that if i create an empty environment with conda, it is empty, there is no package in it. But if i try to create something with pipenv on conda base, conda base is already full of with many django packages. Is it still better to use conda base with pipenv?

I want to create a neat new pipenv environment which is not effected by conda environments and packages installed in it

Answer (score 1):

When Pipenv is sufficient, I do not use Conda. NumPy from PyPI comes in a wheel package that includes OpenBLAS, which can be comparable in performance to Intel MKL, the default BLAS implementation for Conda's NumPy.

But when you do need to use Conda, you can create a new Conda environment, then have Pipenv use that Conda environment.

```sh
conda create -n foo
pipenv --python=$(conda run -n foo which python) --site-packages
```